# How to get the header of an XHR page using puppeteer

Tags: php, puppeteer

I have no knowledge about puppeteer. I try to retrieve header content (such as a cookie, Referrer, etc.) of a specific URL (not the page in goto, but the page retrieve by XHR). Anyone can give me a tip for this?
Here is my code:

```php
$puppeteer = new Puppeteer();
$browser = $puppeteer->launch([
    'args' => [   
    // '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'               
    '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/534.34 PhantomJS/2.0.0 (PhantomJsCloud.com/2.0.1)'               
    ]
]);
$page = $browser->newPage();
$url="https://www.example.com";
echo($url);
$pagestr=$page->goto($url);
$page->waitForTimeout(1000); 
$data = $page->evaluate(JsFunction::createWithBody('return document.documentElement.outerHTML;'));
print_r($data);
$browser->close();
```

An example is to retrieve head information of a specific URL.